# Adding two data frames of different sizes and subsets

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a bunch of transition matrices that look like these.

```
> temp
        31-60 5-30 61-90 Current PaidOff
5-30      283  317     9     500       9
Current     0 2935     0  179989    1689
PaidOff     0    0     0       0       0
```

I want to standardize the size so I've made a 0 matrix with the correct row and column names:

```
> blankMatrix
                  Current 5-30 31-60 61-90 91-120 ChargeOff_Default PaidOff
Current                 0    0     0     0      0                 0       0
5-30                    0    0     0     0      0                 0       0
31-60                   0    0     0     0      0                 0       0
61-90                   0    0     0     0      0                 0       0
91-120                  0    0     0     0      0                 0       0
ChargeOff_Default       0    0     0     0      0                 0       0
PaidOff                 0    0     0     0      0                 0       0
```

Is there a way to easily add the first matrix to the second. So for instance the number 283 would go into position (2,3) automatically. I'm hoping to avoid a long and messy for loop where I constantly iterate and check if the row and column names match.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a matrix of row and column index from the row and column names of *temp* using `expand.grid` and then `blankMatrix[matrix index]` will select values from the index pair in the matrix index; To change the values at the corresponding index, just assign the values to it;

```
temp <- as.matrix(temp)
blankMatrix <- as.matrix(blankMatrix)

matIndex <- as.matrix(expand.grid(rownames(temp), colnames(temp)))
blankMatrix[matIndex] <- temp
blankMatrix
#                  Current X5.30 X31.60 X61.90 X91.120 ChargeOff_Default PaidOff
#Current            179989  2935      0      0       0                 0    1689
#5-30                  500   317    283      9       0                 0       9
#31-60                   0     0      0      0       0                 0       0
#61-90                   0     0      0      0       0                 0       0
#91-120                  0     0      0      0       0                 0       0
#ChargeOff_Default       0     0      0      0       0                 0       0
#PaidOff                 0     0      0      0       0                 0       0
```

Comment: @Psidorn: I'm getting `blankMatrix[matIndex] <- temp
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, matIndex, value = list(`31-60` = c(283L,  : 
  unsupported matrix index in replacement`

Comment: It seems like the `blankMatrix` is a data frame, you need to convert it to matrix for this to work.

Comment: Any way to do this with data frames? The temp matrix is created using "as.data.frame.matrix"

Comment: Actually, converting temp to a matrix and then proceeding works fine. :-)

Comment: Nice answer. An alternative to the line that sets `matIndex` could be: `matIndex <- as.matrix(as.data.frame.table(temp)[1:2])`